# Convert a Word file into Twig keeping Twig directives

Tags: php, html, symfony, twig, phpword

I'm trying to build a formats maker. I want to load a word from the client that have some twig directives like `{{variables}}` and afterward render them in my server with Symfony 2 and passing it some values so the directives like `{{name}}` will be replaced with the data I pass to it, like a normal twig render process.

The word file I'm trying to convert right now

```
Hi I’m a Word file and this is a variable.

{{variable}}
```

It is nothing special.

I am using `PHPWord` and I have the following code:

```
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory;
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Writer\HTML;

if ($filePath)
    $word = IOFactory::load($filePath);

$twigName = 'formats/'.$name.'.html.twig';
$htmlWriter = new HTML($word);
$htmlWriter->save($twigName);

$renderedHTMLPath = realpath($appPath . '/../web/' . $twigName);
$renderedTwig = $this->render($renderedHTMLPath, $params)
```

This is the rendered HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Generated by PHPWord -->
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8" />
      <title>PHPWord</title>
      <style>
         * {
            font-family: Arial;
             font-size: 11pt;
        }
         a.NoteRef {
            text-decoration: none;
        }
         hr {
            height: 1px;
             padding: 0;
             margin: 1em 0;
             border: 0;
             border-top: 1px solid #CCC;
        }
         table {
            border: 1px solid black;
             border-spacing: 0px;
             width : 100%;
        }
         td {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
         .Normal {
            margin-bottom: 8pt;
        }
         .List Paragraph {
            margin-top: 0;
             margin-bottom: 0;
        }

      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <p style="margin-bottom: 0pt;"><span style="font-family: 'Times New Roman';">Hi </span><span style="font-family: 'Times New Roman';">I’m</span><span style="font-family: 'Times New Roman';"> a W</span><span style="font-family: 'Times New Roman';">ord file and </span><span style="font-family: 'Times New Roman';">this</span><span style="font-family: 'Times New Roman';"> </span><span style="font-family: 'Times New Roman';">is</span><span style="font-family: 'Times New Roman';"> a variable.</span></p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <!-- This is the important line, there is where I want the curly braces to stay together to be undestadable for the twig templating process -->
      <p style="margin-bottom: 0pt;"><span style="font-family: 'Times New Roman';">{</span><span style="font-family: 'Times New Roman';">{</span><span style="font-family: 'Times New Roman';">variable</span><span style="font-family: 'Times New Roman';">}</span><span style="font-family: 'Times New Roman';">}</span></p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

The thing here is the rendered html file has styles between the curly braces, I'd like to, somehow, tell `PHPWord` to ignore lines that have double curly braces because I want them to be undestandable for twig templating processor to replace them with the data I will pass to it.

I dont event know if this approach is the correct one so I am entirely open to any suggestion, I would really appreciate them.

Comment: You have to do it the other way around. First create the parsed content with twig and pass this to the word generator

Comment: Hi, the thing here is that I want any user to be able to write down a document and it seems like everyone know how to use word, there they can style it and structure it the way they want without much trouble, just having double curly braces where they want data to be replaced like {{employeeName}} then using my website the word file can be previewed and then saved so anytime a user can reuse format just by clicking on any employee so the data between the curly braces will be replaced with the employee info, twig is only for the preview

Comment: I'm feeling that will cause a lot of problems when for instance the user set the braces to italic, bold, ... Perhaps you should explore [variable fields](https://www.helpandmanual.com/help/hm_working_configoutput_docx_varfields.html) in Word and see how that translate into twig. Perhaps then you could replace the variable with some twig syntax

Comment: Yeah, I think is not the best way neither. I just noticed PHPWord library has something called TemplateProcessor where I can do what I wanted but instead of using double curly braces it is  like ${} and I can use the same library to convert it to html to show the preview so I think I will be using that, ty for ur support